# Which M3 screw / bolt material can be used in dishwasher?

Tags: screws

I have fixed two pair of tongs I use for cooking with M3 screws and bolts.

After a few rounds in the dishwasher rust started forming...

Is there any different M3 screws / bolts material that I could find easily that will not rust in dishwasher?
Or, if non toxic, an anti-rust paint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You want stainless steel

That should be readily available in any hardware store that sells metric.  Stainless + metric *both* can be a little bit specialty, so you need that community hardware store that's been around for 100 years, or McMaster-Carr or equivalent in your territory.

Comment: Stainless and metric is **very** common in Europe, and that is where the OP is... However, finding Whitworth can  be **so** much more challenging.

Comment: @SolarMike Tell me about it... I have stuff with 1/2-12 threads...